# Javascript using ajax function to check for file as a return boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still getting used to javascript, in Java we can create boolean functions that return true or false, I'm triyng to do the same in javascript. I am trying to create a boolean function to check if a certain file is there or not on my webserver. Wondering if what I am doing here makes sense or not?  Here is what I have so far:

```
function isFileThere(){
$.ajax({
    url: /path/to/my/file,
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
        console.log("File is not there!");
        return false;
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
        console.log("File is there! Continue to output status...");
        return true;
    }
});
}

if(isFileThere()) {
            console.log("The file is there, starting interval...");
            startInterval();
} 
else if (!isFileThere()) {
            console.log("The file is NOT there, reseting interval...");
            resetInterval();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use callback, it's common problem for javascript newcomers

In short, callbacks are simple functions that are run when some asynchronous code completed execution, or some event called

```
function isFileThere(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: /path/to/my/file,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function() {
            return callback(false)
        },
        success: function() {
            return callback(true)
        }
    });
}

function myCallback(exist) {
    if(exist) {
         console.log("The file is there, starting interval...");
         startInterval();
    } else {
         console.log("The file is NOT there, reseting interval...");
         resetInterval();
    }
}

isFileThere(myCallback)
```

[Read more](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Probably you've seen them before, for example in Arrays

```
function myCustomCallback(number) { 
    console.log(number)
}
[1, 2, 3].forEach(myCustomCallback)
// actually this is an iterator, but it looks same as callback
// and might be called as callback
```

Comment: ah ok, i see what you mean. Could you walk me through the call back function.